# Components not rendered nor transpiled

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am modifying an already existing web app and I started changing on page of if with react.

When I use createElement, I can successfully show basic elements like buttons and I can also have a feedback when buttons are clicked.

Just for a trial I added another  inside my html and called it "main".
The simple html looks like this:

```html
<script src="app/like_button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app/modal.js" type="text/babel"></script>


<div id="buttons"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Nextly I create my modal.js inside app folder :

```js
// modal trial
class ExampleApp extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
    
    this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleOpenModal () {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }
  
  handleCloseModal () {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>Trigger Modal</button>
        <ReactModal 
           isOpen={this.state.showModal}
           contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example"
        >
          <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
        </ReactModal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const props = {};

ReactDOM.render(<ExampleApp {...props} />, document.getElementById('main'))
```

When I run my app, I get no errors but the react component is not showing up.

I think that it can be something related to babel. I installed it using the information from this: https://babeljs.io/en/setup#installation

I also have a package.json that looks like this:

```js
{
  "name": "--",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Prod instance is at https:--",
  "main": "/public/app/main.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "babel" : {
    "presets": ["es2015", "react" ]
  ,}
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http:--"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I removed several information for privacy.

I hope you can help me solve this.

**UPDATES**
As suggested, I tried installing babel but it seems like I have network related problems. When I run : npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev 
I get this log :

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/global/appl/node.js/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/global/appl/node.js/prod/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'babel-preset-react-app',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose npm-session 75f9a86bb46d1391
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for babel-preset-react-app@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN acruz:80
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 3ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4862ms
10 verbose type system
11 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN acruz:80
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/global/appl/node.js/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
11 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
11 verbose stack     at onerror (/global/appl/node.js/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:100:9)
11 verbose stack     at callbackError (/global/appl/node.js/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:122:5)
11 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
12 verbose cwd /home/user/project_name
13 verbose Linux 4.4.103-92.53-default
14 verbose argv "/global/appl/node.js/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/global/appl/node.js/prod/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "babel-preset-react-app" "--save-dev"
15 verbose node v8.12.0
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error code EAI_AGAIN
18 error errno EAI_AGAIN
19 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN acruz:80
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I actually don't understand what is going on.I remember reading that it can be a network related problem since I am using a proxy as stated in some comments here : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16661

Comment: make sure you installed "@babel/cli"  "@babel/core", since you have installed already "@babel/preset-env" but installed is "babel-core"  instead  "@babel/core" and you can check with this for react-babel-webpack setup https://github.com/jai1331/babel-webpack-jsx

Comment: @Jayavel i tried your suggestion but I'm stuck with the installations. I'm using corporate proxy and i'm having errors related to the network itself. It doesn't look like there is a workaround for it.